# Deleting an object in a tableView cell from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am attempting to delete certain objects from Parse. The user will be able to save posts and I am trying to implement a way for them to delete them. The saved posts can be found in a TableView.

I currently have the following.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Remove") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let query = PFQuery(className: "SavedObjects")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.whereKey("savedByUser", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {

                    object.deleteInBackground()
                }
            }
        })

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


    return [deleteAction]

}
```

The `object.deleteInBackground()` does work, but it deletes all objects that were saved by the user. I would like it to only delete the object that the cell represents.

I have also tried to use `object.deleteInBackgroundWithTarget([indexPath.row], selector: nil)` but have had no luck.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem here.

Comment: same problem! I can't fix it until now

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly, I think you need to add another `query.WhereKey()` filtering by the objectId of the corresponding row saved on Parse. This way the call to `object.deleteInBackground()` will only delete the cell you selected from the TableView. I hope this was helpful!

Valerio